# Perform JOIN in SQLITE on two SELECT statements from the same table

Tags: sqlite

This is how I have a sample table in SQLITE

```
ID  NAME    AGE ADDRESS     SALARY
1   Paul    32  California  20000.0
2   Allen   25  Texas   15000.0
3   Teddy   23  Norway  20000.0
4   Mark    25  Rich-Mond   65000.0
5   David   27  Texas   85000.0
6   Kim 22  South-Hall  45000.0
7   Paul    32  California  20000.0
8   Allen   25  Texas   15000.0
9   Teddy   23  Norway  20000.0
```

What I want to achieve is a join on my SQLITE table on these two queries

```
select AGE, count(*)  as SALARYLESSTHAN45 from company where salary < 45000 group by salary 

select AGE, count(*)  as SALARYMORETHAN45 from company where salary > 45000 group by salary
```

I tried the following

```
select AGE, count(*)  as SALARYLESSTHAN45 from company where salary < 45000 group by salary  ) T1
INNER JOIN
select AGE, count(*)  as SALARYMORETHAN45 from company where salary > 45000 group by salary  ) T2
ON T1.AGE = T2.AGE
```

but cannot get this to work...

Can someone share an example of how to achieve this in SQLITE ?

Comment: These queries do not make sense because you get a random age from each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join on two different tables would look like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM Tab1 JOIN Tab2 ON ...
```

To do the join on the result of a query, you have to replace the table name with a subquery:

```
select AGE,
       SALARYLESSTHAN45,
       SALARYMORETHAN45
from (select AGE,
             count(*) as SALARYLESSTHAN45
      from company
      where salary < 45000
      group by salary)
join (select AGE,
             count(*) as SALARYMORETHAN45
      from company
      where salary > 45000
      group by salary)
using (AGE);
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Not sure why I was struggling so much to get this done. Just a follow up question on similar lines....How can I do a FULL Outer Join in this scenario and replace NULLs with (say) zeroes

Comment: To ask a question, click "Ask Question".